# How to paste from multiple clipboards vim without leaving insert mode?

Tags: vim, clipboard

Suppose you are typing in vim and there are 5 common expressions that you need to insert into the text over and over.

Is there a way you can tell vim to paste from multiple clipboards **without** leaving insert mode?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

ctrl-r follwed by the register lets you paste the contents of a register without leaving insert mode.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd><kbd>"</kbd>  Put from the default register

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>  Put from register d

By the way, in vim they're called "registers" not "clipboards" and the verb is "put", not "paste". (Reminder, to get a visual selection into register d, you would use <kbd>"dy</kbd>)

Comment: This is great! Also, how did you format text to look like keyboard buttons? I looked for something in the FAQs on SuperUser markdown but didn't find it.

Comment: Try with <kbd> tag.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need those expressions to come from clipboards?

You can easily do something like this:

```
:iab some_unique_string foo bar baz
```

And vim will replace "some_unique_string" with "foo bar baz" as soon as you enter it in insert mode.

Answer (score 1):

If its always the same expressions, e.g. in java programming things like "private static void main(String... args)" you can use a plugin like [snipmate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540). You can configure it so you can just type "main`<Tab>`" and it will exapnd to the long java code needed, and it has more cool features...